# ERROR : XMLHttpRequest error in flutter while using weather API

Tags: flutter, weather-api, flutter-debug

here i use a weather API. while do debugging it comes with an error as,

Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 908:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22                                                                                    
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1687:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 160:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 593:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1232:7                                             
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37332:58                              
at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:51980/dart_sdk.js:5388:12)
at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:51980/dart_sdk.js:40987:16)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:51980/dart_sdk.js:40981:13)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:51980/dart_sdk.js:40808:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:51980/dart_sdk.js:40814:13)
at http://localhost:51980/dart_sdk.js:36279:9

my flutter code is:

```
    String searchApiUrl = 'https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=';
    String locationApiUrl = 'https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/';


    void fetchSearch(String input) async {
     var searchResult = await http.get(Uri.parse(searchApiUrl + input), headers: {"Accept": 
      "application/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"});
  
     var result = json.decode(searchResult.body)[0];

   setState(() {
    location = result["title"];
    woeid = result["woeid"];
});
```

}

```
    void fetchLocation() async {
     var locationResult = await http.get(Uri.parse(locationApiUrl + woeid.toString()), 
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"});
     var result = json.decode(locationResult.body);
     var consolidated_weather = result["consolidated_weather"];
     var data = consolidated_weather[0];

   setState(() {
    temperature = data["the_temp"].round();
    weather = data["weather_state_name"].replaceAll(' ','').toLowerCase();
});
```

}

```
   void onTextFieldSubmitted(String input){
    fetchSearch(input);
    fetchLocation();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In `fetchLocation` you are depending on the `woeid` value coming from `fetchSearch`, but you do not wait for the result in `onTextFieldSubmitted`. Try this:

```
void onTextFieldSubmitted(String input) async {
    await fetchSearch(input);
    await fetchLocation(); // await in this line might not be needed
}
```